# Phpmyadmin is not opening

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed XAMPP in Ubuntu 18, but when I open Phpmyadmin it shows only some weird words that cover the whole screen . What could be the problem? 
I would post a picture but, my reputation in stackoverflow is still low
Please I need some help

Comment: without information its difficult

Comment: Could you copy and paste the first bit? It could be that the PHP interpreter isn't properly configured and you're seeing the PHP source code rather than the result you're supposed to see.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's due to php-gettext package, follow the answers here  :

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12177

Hope it works for you as it did for me.